# ssrs mail scheduler not to send mail if data is empty

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I cannot able to stop the ssrs subscription mail if the data is null or empty.
I am sending mail of a report for every 30 minutes but i am not supposed to send the mail if the data is empty ..

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2005/07/29/445080.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another way of handling this is to fire an error in your query if it returns no rows:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLES)=0
RAISEERROR <custom error message>
ELSE
(
Run your query
)
```

The subscription will not send the email if it encounters RAISERROR.